# M2- How to get thumbnails of associated products on a grouped product from image cache

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-images, grouped-products

I'm trying to bring simple products thumbnails of a grouped product on product detail page. I can show their thumbnails easily in **Magento1** but I am not able to do this in **Magento2**.

In **Magento1**, My simple products can be shown like this :

[image]

So I tried this code at below located file

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/default/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');?>

<!-- add simple products(associated product) thumbnails -->
        <td>
            <?php $image_url = $imageHelper->init($_item, 'grouped_list_product_thumbnail')->setImageFile($_item->getFile())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl(); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>">
        </td>

<!-- add simple products(associated product) thumbnails -->
```

If I run this code, my code gets images as placeholder, not from cache. so it doesn't come out. Actually, we did migrate from *Magento1* and media folder also was **migrated manually**. I want to get these image from cache folder. How can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just overwrite the file in the  custom theme app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml and paste the code in your phtml file

```
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>
<?php $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Image') ?></th>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
        <?php  $item = $_item->getId() ;?>
        <?php $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($item); ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Image')); ?>">
                  <?php $imageUrl   = $block->getImage($product, 'product_thumbnail_image'); ?> 
                    <div class="group-img-<?php echo $_item->getEntityId(); ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php echo $imageUrl->toHtml(); ?></a>
                </div>
            </td>

                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')); ?>" class="col qty">
                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                    <div class="control qty">
                        <input type="number" name="super_group[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               maxlength="12"
                               value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                               title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Qty') ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                               data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="qty-changer">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-inc"><i class="porto-icon-up-dir"></i></a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-dec"><i class="porto-icon-down-dir"></i></a>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Availability') ?>">
                        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?php echo $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not get images from cache but it might point you towards what you need. This gets product thumbnails from Grouped Product.

You need to add a new module and override this from /vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php:

```
public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
{
    if (!$product->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
        $associatedProducts = [];

        $this->setSaleableStatus($product);

        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection(
            $product
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            ['name', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id']
        )->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->getStoreFilter($product)
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'status',
            ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
        );

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $associatedProducts[] = $item;
        }

        $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
    }
    return $product->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
}
```

With this (Added thumbnail. Look up the name for another type of image.):

```
public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
{
    if (!$product->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
        $associatedProducts = [];

        $this->setSaleableStatus($product);

        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection(
            $product
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            ['name', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id', 'thumbnail']
        )->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->getStoreFilter($product)
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'status',
            ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
        );

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $associatedProducts[] = $item;
        }

        $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
    }
    return $product->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
}
```

Then override vendor/magento/module-grouped-product/view/frontend//frontend/templates/product/view/type/Grouped.phtml with your own. Just copy that file to your vendor/theme/Magento_GroupedProduct/...

For thumbnail add this:

```
        <?php $associatedProductThumbnail = $block->escapeHtml($_item->getThumbnail()) ?>
    <?php $associatedProductThumbnail = '/pub/media/catalog/product' . $associatedProductThumbnail ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this just follow the guidelines as described below.

Create a custom module at below location

> Magento_root/app/code/{Vendor}/{ModuleName}

Create below file into your module as per there locations given here.

> 1. registration.php
> 2. etc/module.xml
> 3. etc/view.xml
> 4. etc/di.xml
> 5. view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml
> 6. view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml
> 7. Model/Product/Type/Grouped.php

Now put below code into the respective files I am not putting here content of **`registraton.php`** & **`module.xml`** as because it might be well understood to you or you can get it from any where.

**view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="product_page_image_group_product" type="thumbnail">
                <width>100</width>
                <height>100</height>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="\Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" type="{Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" />
</config>
```

**grouped.phtml**

```
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>

        <tbody>
            <tr>

                <?php /* code for image thumbnail start */?>

                <?php 
                $imageUrl = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($_item, 'product_page_image_group_product')
                            ->setImageFile($_item->getThumbnail())->getUrl();
                            ?>
                <td><div class="group-img-<?php echo $_item->getEntityId(); ?>" data-role="group-image" data-product-id="<?php echo $_item->getEntityId(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>"></div></td>

                <?php /* code for image thumbnail end */?>

                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                    <div class="control qty">
                        <input type="number"
                               name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                               data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=group-image]": {
                "Webindiainc_Groupedproduct/js/group-image-renderer": {
                    "jsongroupimageConfig": "<?php echo $_item->getEntityId() ?>",
                    "mediaCallback": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMediaCallback() ?>"
                }
            }
        }
</script>
```

**catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product.info.form.content">
            <block class="Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped" name="product.info.grouped" before="product.info.addtocart" template="{Vendor}_{ModuleName}::product/view/type/grouped.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Grouped.php**

```
<?php

namespace {Vendor}\{ModuleName}\Model\Product\Type;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class Grouped extends \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped
{


    /**
     * Retrieve array of associated products
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
    {
        if (!$product->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
            $associatedProducts = [];

            $this->setSaleableStatus($product);

            $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection(
                $product
            )->addAttributeToSelect(
                ['name', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'tax_class_id', 'thumbnail']
            )->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter(
                $this->getStoreFilter($product)
            )->addAttributeToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
            );

            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $associatedProducts[] = $item;
            }

            $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
        }
        return $product->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
    }

}
?>
```

> Note: After completing with this stuff just do run below commands.
>
> ```
> php bin/magento module:enable {Vendor}_{ModuleName}
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup-static-content:deploy
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This works in Magento 2.4

Overwrite the file app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/default/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.phtml

Edit thead

```
<thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() || $block->showButton()) : ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>
```

Add this td inside the tbody tag (above the Product Name td)

```
<td><img src="<?= $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$_item->getImage() ?>"/ width="75px"></td>
```

My full grouped.phtml file is:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Grouped product data template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\BaseImage
 * @var $block \Magento\GroupedProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Grouped
 */
?>
<?php $block->setPreconfiguredValue(); ?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $_associatedProducts = $block->getAssociatedProducts(); ?>
<?php $_hasAssociatedProducts = count($_associatedProducts) > 0; ?>

<?php $objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
<?php $productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository'); ?>

<div class="table-wrapper grouped">
    <table class="table data grouped" id="super-product-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Grouped product items') ?></caption>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th class="col item" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <th class="col qty" scope="col"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></th>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <?php if ($_hasAssociatedProducts): ?>
        <?php foreach ($_associatedProducts as $_item): ?>
            <?php $childProduct = $productRepository->get($_item->getSku()); ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="<?= $block->getUrl('pub/media/catalog').'product'.$_item->getImage() ?>"/ width="75px"></td>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col item">
                    <strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                    <div class="sku"><?= $_item->getSku() ?></div>
                    <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)): ?>
                        <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)): ?>
                            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                     <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>" class="col qty">
                <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()) : ?>
                    <div class="control qty">
                        <input type="number"
                               name="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               data-selector="super_group[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>]"
                               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getQty() * 1 ?>"
                               title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{'validate-grouped-qty':'#super-product-table'}"
                               data-errors-message-box="#validation-message-box"/>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <div class="stock unavailable" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Availability') ?>">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Out of stock') ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </td>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </tr>
            <?php if ($block->getCanShowProductPrice($_product)
                && $block->getCanShowProductPrice($_item)
                && trim($block->getProductPriceHtml(
                    $_item,
                    \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                ))): ?>
                <tr class="row-tier-price">
                    <td colspan="2">
                        <?= $block->getProductPriceHtml(
                            $_item,
                            \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice::PRICE_CODE
                        ) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="unavailable"
                    colspan="<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>4<?php else : ?>3<?php endif; ?>">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('No options of this product are available.') ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="validation-message-box"></div>
```